# Should we create the [pypsa] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I am one of the maintainers in the ["pypsa-universe"](https://pypsa-meets-earth.github.io/projects.html). We host, among others, one of the most popular open source energy system optimization frameworks called [PyPSA](https://github.com/PyPSA/PyPSA) with 822 GitHub stars. Currently, there are not many questions on Stack Overflow ([see examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pypsa)), since we answer all questions on [our Discord server](https://discord.gg/AnuJBk23FU) (500 users) and our [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/group/pypsa) mailing list. In general, we get about 3-5 questions on average per day and expect that number to increase. To make questions and answers more accessible over the web, we would like to start with only one tag for [pypsa].

Please, let me know if this is possible and how we would proceed. Unfortunately, no one in our community has yet 1500 reputation points.

Initial tag wiki excerpt:

> "PyPSA is an open source framework for simulating and optimising modern power and energy systems. Use this tag for questions about using or developing PyPSA.

Tag wiki description:

Could extend this [Readme](https://github.com/PyPSA/PyPSA#pypsa---python-for-power-system-analysis)

Comment: The [site search for PyPSA](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=pypsa%20is%3aquestion) only turns up a total of 14 questions, the newest from December. Does that volume really warrant creating a tag up front? Are there any experts here that would be using the tag to find questions to answer?

Comment: Yes (I'm a maintainer of some of the PyPSA-related tools). We're in a bit of a hen-egg situation right now were we redirect a lot of questions we get to our google groups mailing list to consolidate answers there.

Comment: We have 810 questions only in google mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/pypsa and would like to direct everyone to Stackoverflow by default as we think it's the best solution. [Our developer core][https://pypsa.org/#people] willl be using the tag.

Comment: Looking through the first fifteen questions on your google groups, none of them would fare well on [SO]. So presumably just redirecting them here would be... unwise. How exactly are you "redirecting" people, and what expectations do you set for them?

Comment: Agreed, not all questions from our other channels are suited for SO and I would not be our goal to move all to SO. I think more programming-related questions like e.g. [this one](https://groups.google.com/g/pypsa/c/GsJ_njpgGlo), which are also related an [existing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snakemake) would be well suited for SO. As for "redirecting": We usually try redirecting questions we receive in private to our ML. We also refer to the ML and Discord server in our documentation in our GitHub repositories.

Comment: We are aware that not all questions are suitable for Stackoverflow as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Our approach to avoid unecessary Q's on SO would be to clearly outline where to ask what questions e.g. in our README, documentation and the [GitHub issue template](https://github.com/PyPSA/PyPSA/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Re *"answer all questions on our Discord server (500 users)"*: Then you should be able to launch with an awesome [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) on day one. Does it already exist? Some tag wikis have them, e.g., [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) (now destroyed, but it is in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607050/revisions))

Comment: It looks like one of our high-reputation users has gone ahead and created [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypsa), so you should be all set.  I've copied over your proposed tag wiki excerpt as well.